# How to iterate over a JSON array and log the attributes that have a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a response body that looks like this

```
{
   "data_sets":[
    { 
           "author": {
               "name": "foo"
           },
           "category": "zip",
           "client": true,
           "data_type": "zip",
           "index": "completed",
           "id": 200,
           "params": {}
    },
    {
           "author": {
               "name": "foo2"
           },
           "category": "zip",
           "client": true,
           "data_type": "zip",
           "index": "completed",
           "id": 190,
           "params": {}
    }]}
```

I am trying to iterate over my thousands of datasets in my postman test and just simply console.log the id that equals the id in my environmental variable. For this case, let's say that is 190. I'm trying something like this but it isn't working. It isn't failing but it's not giving me my expected output.

Here is my code in postman

```
    pm.test("the response has the right id", () => {
    id_dataset = pm.environment.get("id");
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.data_sets.length; i++)
   if(jsonData.data_sets[i].id == id_dataset)
     console.log(jsonData.data_sets[i].id);
    });
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `i < jsonData.data_sets.length` (Note that you can also replace the loop with `const data_set = jsonData.data_sets.find(item => item.id === id_dataset);`)

Comment: (On an unrelated note: the server response is text in JSON format. `pm.response.json();` parses that JSON text, which results in an object. This object in turn contains `.data_sets`, which is an array. There's no such thing as a "JSON array" or "JSON object".)

Comment: The JSON is invalid. It's missing some commas, the second element is missing `}`.

Comment: @Shultz please check my solution using the array method `find()` and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I've added optional chaining `?.id` to my solution to prevent an error from being thrown whenever the ID is not present.

Answer (score 1):

We should be able to use `find()` to quickly search through all the records and find the record with the matching id of `190`. Try this:

```js
pm.test("the response has the right id", () => {
    id_dataset = pm.environment.get("id"); // 190
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    console.log(jsonData.data_sets.find(set => set.id === id_dataset)?.id);
});
```

Here is the same logic in vanilla JS:

```js
let id_dataset = 190;

let data_sets = [ { "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} }, { "author": { "name": "foo2" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 190, "params": {} }];

console.log(data_sets.find(set => set.id === id_dataset)?.id);
```

Comment: @Shultz would you be free to chat about this? It looks like you may have resolved your issue but I would still like to test with my example as I think it will simplify your logic overall: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231173/question-67096991

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting `.length` inside your for

```js
  const jsonData = {data_sets: [ { "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} },{ "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} },{ "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": false, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} }, { "author": { "name": "foo2" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 190, "params": {} }]};

 const id_dataset = 200;
 for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.data_sets.length; i++)
   if(jsonData.data_sets[i].id == id_dataset)
     console.log(jsonData.data_sets[i].id);
```

you can use `map` too:

```js
const jsonData = {data_sets: [ { "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} },{ "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} },{ "author": { "name": "foo" }, "category": "zip", "client": false, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 200, "params": {} }, { "author": { "name": "foo2" }, "category": "zip", "client": true, "data_type": "zip", "index": "completed", "id": 190, "params": {} }]};

const id_dataset = 200;

 jsonData.data_sets.map(item=>item.id==id_dataset && console.log(item.id))
```

Comment: Use `forEach` rather than `map` if you're not using the result.

Comment: I changed my code to have those updates but there is still no output in the logs

Comment: if you want to see a console.log for testing purposes only, it's better to write less code

Comment: @Shultz could you provide the result of `console.log(jsonData)`? proabably you need to parse the response with `.json()`

Comment: my end goal is to assert that lets say id of 190 has a "client":true, but that wasn't working so I'm going step by step and figuring out each part

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian when I do console.log(jsonData) nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: end goal is something like pm.assert(jsonData.data_sets[i].client).to.eq_true); only if the id = 190 which is must iterate through the data_sets array to find

Comment: to do that you just have to add another if inside the `for`, it is strange that `jsonData` does not print anything. you can try doing the test instead of a console.log

Comment: @MartinGainzaKoulaksezian you code snippet worked, however, any ideas why any other json object doesn't work such as console.log(jsonData.data_sets[i].client);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231142/discussion-between-shultz-and-martin-gainza-koulaksezian).

Comment: it should works! if not probably the jsonData structure is different against the structure that you posted